# React and Firebase connection for get data and post data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to put the data in Firebase between li tags. For example; Room Code: {roomCode} but I cannot access the data I received from Firebase as I want.

This is the only way I can see the data in the console:

[image: console image]

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, Component} from "react";
import fire from './fire';



function DataConnection() {

    const [rooms, setRooms] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const db = fire.firestore();
        return db.collection('rooms').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            const postData = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => postData.push({...doc.data(), id:doc.id}));
            setRooms(postData);
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(rooms);


    return(
        <div>
 
          
        </div>
    );};

export default DataConnection;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres nowhere in the code you are mapping the results of rooms into you return statement

```
function DataConnection() {

const [rooms, setRooms] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    const db = fire.firestore();
    return db.collection('rooms').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const postData = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => postData.push({...doc.data(), id:doc.id}));
        setRooms(postData);
    });
}, []);

console.log(rooms);
rooms.map((el) => {
  return (<><li>Roomname: { el.roomName} </li><li>Roomcode: {el.roomCode}</li></>)
}
```

Comment: I want to put them into 'return' like:  return ( <div> <li> roomCode: roomCode </li> <li> roomName: roomName </li>  )

Comment: not a problem. i updated the code snippet so you can have that result.

Comment: Sorry to comeback late. Thank you for helping me solve this simple problem, I am grateful.